# C# Использование Entity Framework вне конвейера обработки запросов ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

**Предисловие:**
Пишу ВебАпи, на ASP.NET Core 2.0. Не коммерческий проект, исключительно для собственных образовательных целей. Работать будет как Feedly, то есть - агрегатор новостных лент.

*Я плохо знаю Entity Framework и возможно решение элментарно, но я его не знаю и найти не смог.*

**Суть проблемы:**
После добавления нового новостного канала в АПИ я отвечаю пользователю что все ок и хочу в пуле потоков запустить процесс выгрузки новостей в БД моего АПИ. Далее - пользователь сможет просматривать новости даже если новостной ресурс будет недоступен получая их из БД приложения. 
Делаю я это следующим образом:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new FeedParser(_context).Parse, request.ResourceUrl);
```

FeedParser содержит следующий конструктор:

```
private UsersDataContext _db;        
public FeedParser(UsersDataContext context)
            {
                if (context != null) _db = context;
            }
```

Но когда я вызываю **_db.SaveChanges();** получаю эксепшн:

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is
>   disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and
>   then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
>   application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the
>   context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are
>   using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection
>   container take care of disposing context instances. Object name:
>   'UsersDataContext'.

**Я это понимаю следующим образом:**
Так как context ссылочный тип и формируется еще в классе Startup по завершении основного потока он уничтожается (пул потоков имеет очень низкий приоритет и CLR не обращает внимания на подобные ссылки). Опять таки, могу ошибаться. Плаваю в этой теме. 
Ок, я бы инициализировал новый экземпляр DbContext в FeedParser, но как не пробовал - пока не выходит. 
Подскажите как это реализовать или где прочесть? Уже дошло до того, что подумываю ADO.NET использовать в этом классе, но это уже будет совсем извращением.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже не спец (давно не трогал asp.net), но, как я понял суть (но я могу ошибаться):

1. При резолве каких то зависимостей в .net core, каждая зависимость резолвится в каком то scope
2. При создании контроллера Scope привязан к запросу
3. Когда вы посылаете что то в отдельный поток и завершаете запрос, то с завершением запроса завершается scope, который убивает DbContext

что бы я сделал. Я бы переделал класс FeedParser

```
public class FeedParser
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public FeedParser(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task Parse(....)
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            using (var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDbContext>())
            {
                ... make changes
                await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И регистрировал бы его так в Setup классе

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>... your options here); // register your context
    services.AddSingleton<FeedParser, FeedParser>();        
}
```

Ну и резолвил бы его в контроллере, где надо

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(FeedParser parser)
    {
    ......
    }
}
```