# Как получить доступ к контексту базы данных в синглтоне .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, singleton

У меня есть репозиторий (интерфейс)

```
public interface IPushTemplateRepository
{
    IQueryable<PushTemplate> PushTemplates { get; }
}
```

и реализация

```
public class PushTemplateRepository : IPushTemplateRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationContext;

    public PushTemplateRepository(ApplicationDbContext applicationContext)
    {
        _applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<PushTemplate> PushTemplates => _applicationContext.PushTemplates;
}
```

И вот такой вот класс

```
public class PushingScheduler
{
    private readonly ILogger<PushingScheduler> _logger;
    private readonly IPushTemplateRepository _pushTemplateRepository;
    private readonly IPushRepository _pushRepository;
    private readonly ISenderLogRepository _senderLogRepository;
    private readonly IDistributionRepository _distributionRepository;

    // services
    private readonly IPushTemplateService _pushTemplateService;
    private readonly ISendPushService _sendPushService;

    private const int TimerIntervalInSeconds = 60;
    private Timer _aTimer;
    private int _executionCount;

    public PushingScheduler(IPushRepository pushRepository,
        IPushTemplateRepository pushTemplateRepository, ILogger<PushingScheduler> logger,
        IPushTemplateService pushTemplateService, ISendPushService sendPushService,
        ISenderLogRepository senderLogRepository, IDistributionRepository distributionRepository)
    {
        _pushRepository = pushRepository;
        _pushTemplateRepository = pushTemplateRepository;
        _logger = logger;
        _pushTemplateService = pushTemplateService;
        _sendPushService = sendPushService;
        _senderLogRepository = senderLogRepository;
        _distributionRepository = distributionRepository;

        _executionCount = _senderLogRepository.SenderLogs.Count();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending is started ...");
        _aTimer = new Timer(OnTimedEvent,
            null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds));
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _aTimer?.Dispose();
        _aTimer = null;
    }

    public bool IsWorking => _aTimer != null;

    private async void OnTimedEvent(object state)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var next = now.AddSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds);

        _aTimer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

        try
        {
            await Send();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            var diff = next - DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (diff.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
            {
                _aTimer?.Change(diff,
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds));
            }
            else
            {
                OnTimedEvent(state);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task Send()
    {
        var logMessage = new StringBuilder();

        logMessage.AppendLine($"Начинаю рассылку № {_executionCount}.");

        // Получаем все активные шаблоны (ТУТ СТАРАЯ ИНФА, ЕСЛИ КТО ТО ОБНОВИЛ PushTemplate)
        var templates = _pushTemplateRepository.PushTemplates.Where(x => x.isActive)
            .Include(x => x.Messages)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.PushLang)
            .Include(x => x.Category)
            .Include(x => x.AdvertiserPushTemplates)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Advertiser)
            .ToList();
           // бизнес-логика далее ...
    }
}
```

Это таймер. Из моего контроллера я могу запустить его или остановить. И будет вызываться метод `Send()` раз в минуту например.

Вот пример инъекции зависимостей из `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddTransient<IPushTemplateRepository, PushTemplateRepository>();
services.AddSingleton<PushingScheduler>();
```

Вся проблема в том, что когда я запускаю из контроллера на выполнение мой таймер у меня те есть те экземпляры репозиториев, которые были при запуске приложения. Если я что то обновлю (например какой нибудь `PushTemplate`), то результата я не увижу. Как мне в синглтоне получить актуальный контекст базы данных без перезапуска приложения после каждого обновления данных? Я видел советы касательно разных кейсов с контекстом базы данных в синглтоне, но конкретных решений найти не удалось. Тем более, касательно моего случая с таймером.

### Update

Огромное спасибо пользователю tym32167 за его ответы! Похоже этот человек отлично знает C#.

Я смог написать такой код и это работает:

```
public class PushingScheduler
{
    private readonly ILogger<PushingScheduler> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    // services
    private readonly IPushTemplateService _pushTemplateService;
    private readonly ISendPushService _sendPushService;

    private const int TimerIntervalInSeconds = 60;
    private Timer _aTimer;
    private int _executionCount;

    public PushingScheduler(
        ILogger<PushingScheduler> logger,
        IPushTemplateService pushTemplateService, ISendPushService sendPushService,
        IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _pushTemplateService = pushTemplateService;
        _sendPushService = sendPushService;
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending is started ...");
        _aTimer = new Timer(OnTimedEvent,
            null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds));
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _aTimer?.Dispose();
        _aTimer = null;
    }

    public bool IsWorking => _aTimer != null;

    private async void OnTimedEvent(object state)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var next = now.AddSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds);

        _aTimer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

        try
        {
            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                using (var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>())
                {
                    await Send(ctx);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            var diff = next - DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (diff.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
            {
                _aTimer?.Change(diff,
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds));
            }
            else
            {
                OnTimedEvent(state);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task Send(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
    {
        var _senderLogRepository = new SenderLogRepository(ctx);
        var _pushTemplateRepository = new PushTemplateRepository(ctx);
        var _distributionRepository = new DistributionRepository(ctx);
        var _pushRepository = new PushRepository(ctx);

        var logMessage = new StringBuilder();

        _executionCount = _senderLogRepository.SenderLogs.Count();

        logMessage.AppendLine($"Начинаю рассылку № {_executionCount}.");

        // Получаем все активные шаблоны
        var templates = _pushTemplateRepository.PushTemplates.Where(x => x.isActive)
            .Include(x => x.Messages)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.PushLang)
            .Include(x => x.Category)
            .Include(x => x.AdvertiserPushTemplates)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Advertiser)
            .ToList();
```

Пусть это выглядит странно, главное работает. Хотя наверняка можно было бы изящнее.

### Update 2

К сожалению, приведенное выше решение оказалось нерабочим. Я пришел вот к такому решению:

```
public class PushingScheduler
{
    private readonly ILogger<PushingScheduler> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    private readonly IPushRepository _pushRepository;
    private readonly ISenderLogRepository _senderLogRepository;
    private readonly IDistributionRepository _distributionRepository;


    // services
    private readonly IPushTemplateService _pushTemplateService;
    private readonly ISendPushService _sendPushService;

    private const int TimerIntervalInSeconds = 60;
    private Timer _aTimer;
    private int _executionCount;

    public PushingScheduler(
        ILogger<PushingScheduler> logger,
        IPushTemplateService pushTemplateService, ISendPushService sendPushService,
        IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, IPushRepository pushRepository, ISenderLogRepository senderLogRepository, IDistributionRepository distributionRepository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _pushTemplateService = pushTemplateService;
        _sendPushService = sendPushService;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        _pushRepository = pushRepository;
        _senderLogRepository = senderLogRepository;
        _distributionRepository = distributionRepository;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Sending is started ...");
        _aTimer = new Timer(OnTimedEvent,
            null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds));
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _aTimer?.Dispose();
        _aTimer = null;
    }

    public bool IsWorking => _aTimer != null;

    private async void OnTimedEvent(object state)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var next = now.AddSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds);

        _aTimer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

        try
        {
            await Send();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            var diff = next - DateTime.UtcNow;
            if (diff.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
            {
                _aTimer?.Change(diff,
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimerIntervalInSeconds));
            }
            else
            {
                OnTimedEvent(state);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task Send()
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var _pushTemplateRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IPushTemplateRepository>();
            /*var _distributionRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDistributionRepository>();
            var _senderLogRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISenderLogRepository>();
            var _pushRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPushRepository>();*/

            _executionCount = _senderLogRepository.SenderLogs.Count();

            var logMessage = new StringBuilder();

            logMessage.AppendLine($"Начинаю рассылку № {_executionCount}.");

            // Получаем все активные шаблоны
            var templates = _pushTemplateRepository.PushTemplates.Where(x => x.isActive)
                .Include(x => x.Messages)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.PushLang)
                .Include(x => x.Category)
                .Include(x => x.AdvertiserPushTemplates)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Advertiser)
                .ToList();

            if (templates.Count == 0)
            {
                logMessage.AppendLine("Нет шаблонов");
                return;
            }

            foreach (var pushTemplate in templates)
            {
                var customers = _pushTemplateService.ShowCustomersForCurrentTemplate(pushTemplate).ToList();

                logMessage.AppendLine($"Шаблон {pushTemplate.PushTemplateId}.");

                List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> responseTasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

                var pushes = new List<Push>();

                foreach (var customer in customers)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.Application?.FcmServerKey) ||
                        string.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.FcmRegistrationId))
                    {
                        logMessage.AppendLine(
                            $"Для клиента {customer.CustomerId} не установлены FCMServerKey или FcmRegistrationId. Пуш клиент не получит.");
                        continue;
                    }

                    PushTemplateMessage templateMessage =
                        pushTemplate.Messages.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                            x.PushLang.LangCode == customer.Locale);

                    if (templateMessage == null)
                    {
                        logMessage.AppendLine(
                            $"Для клиента {customer.CustomerId} с локалью {customer.Locale} нет сообщения. Пуш клиент не получит.");
                        continue;
                    }

                    var push = new Push
                    {
                        Customer = customer,
                        PushTemplate = pushTemplate,
                        Category = pushTemplate.Category?.Name,
                        IntervalType = pushTemplate.IntervalType,
                        TemplateType = pushTemplate.TemplateType,
                        TopDateTimeBorder = pushTemplate.TopDateTimeBorder,
                        BottomDateTimeBorder = pushTemplate.BottomDateTimeBorder,
                        ClientStartDateTime = pushTemplate.ClientStartDateTime,
                        PackageId = customer.Application.AppId,
                        Advertiser = customer.Application.Advertiser?.Name,
                        LangCode = templateMessage.PushLang.LangCode,
                        PushTitle = templateMessage.PushTitle,
                        PushBody = templateMessage.PushMessage,
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        responseTasks.Add(_sendPushService.SendAsync(customer.Application.FcmServerKey,
                            customer.FcmRegistrationId,
                            push));
                        pushes.Add(push);
                    }
                    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                    {
                        logMessage.AppendLine($"Исключение во время отправки! Сообщение: {ex.Message}.");
                    }
                }

                // рассылка всех пушей одновременно! 
                var responses = await Task.WhenAll(responseTasks);

                // готовим инфу по рассылке для конкретного шаблона
                var distribution = new Distribution
                {
                    PushTemplate = pushTemplate,
                    CustomerIds = new List<int>()
                };

                var count = 0;
                foreach (var response in responses)
                {
                    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    pushes[count].FCMResponse = responseBody;

                    // если успешный http код и успешный код отправки от FCM
                    var responseJObj = (JObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
                    var successFcmAnswer = responseJObj.SelectToken("success")?.ToObject<int>();
                    pushes[count].Sent = response.IsSuccessStatusCode && successFcmAnswer == 1;

                    distribution.CustomerIds.Add(pushes[count].Customer.CustomerId);

                    logMessage.AppendLine($"FCM ответ: {pushes[count].FCMResponse}.");

                    logMessage.AppendLine($"Пуш получат: {pushes[count].Customer.CustomerId}.");
                    logMessage.AppendLine($"Заголовок: {pushes[count].PushTitle}.");
                    logMessage.AppendLine($"Сообщение {pushes[count].PushBody}.");

                    count++;
                }

                if (count > 0)
                {
                    await _distributionRepository.SaveAsync(distribution);
                }

                await _pushRepository.SaveAsync(pushes);
            }

            logMessage.AppendLine($"Рассылка № {_executionCount} завершена.");

            await _senderLogRepository.SaveAsync(new SenderLog
            {
                Message = logMessage.ToString()
            });

            _logger.LogInformation(logMessage.ToString());
            _executionCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Однако я сталкиваюсь с тем, что PostgreSQL ругается на дубликат первичного ключа. Это происходит на строчке

```
            if (count > 0)
            {
                await _distributionRepository.SaveAsync(distribution);
            }

            await _pushRepository.SaveAsync(pushes);
```

Одна из этих записей на сохранение дает ошибку дубликата первичного ключа. Такое чувство, что если я использую конструкцию `using() {...}` EF забывает, что у него есть в базе записи и пытается создать дочерние сущности сохраняемого объекта.

#### Update 3

Все дело в `IServiceScopeFactory`. Если убрать ее, то ошибка с дублированием первичных ключей пропадает пропадает. Однако тогда я возвращаюсь к ошибке, при которой я не вижу изменений в базе из синглтона.

Comment: [Как пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849310/179763)

Comment: [Создание scope: разница между IServiceProvider и IServiceScopeFactory](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/987911/179763)

Comment: Спасибо! Я обязательно изучу на досуге. Я реализовал так, как было в указанном вами ответе. Работает!

Comment: Если я использую самую первую версию таймера (просто обычной инъекцией зависимостей) то я получаю "зациклившийся" со старыми данными контекст БД. Если я пытаюсь получить репозиторий из IServiceScopeFactory то я действительно получаю обновленные данные. Но далее, при любом сохранении EF ругается на дубликат первичного ключа и пытается создать сущности из сохраняемой сущности. То есть если `Push` содержит ссылку на `Application`  то EF пытается создать `Application` и падает с руганью на то, что такой PK уже занят. Такая палка о двух концах. Не знаю, как решить.

Comment: _Я пришёл к решению_ - Вот и опубликуйте решение как ответ.

Comment: Вопрос преврашается из проблемы получения контекста БД в сингтоне в проблему [сохранения данных в pg](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/367). Думаю. нужно либо переформулировать этот вопрос, либо новый вопрос задать.

Comment: Да, там действительно палка о двух концах. Либо одна проблема, либо другая. Я позже опубликую как я решил это.